# Angular / SCSS : animation not applied on element

Tags: css, angular, animation, sass

I have a post component and this post component has a comment section. When I click comments I want to show the comments of users. I am able to show these comments, but I wanted to add a nice looking animation to make the transition between open and closed smoother. Unfortunately the animation doesn't get applied. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

**This is what it looks like. I click the comments text and then it displays the comments. Right now it opens without animations, despite the code I added below.**

[image]

**template code: I added the index to the class to make sure I get a nice stagger effect**

```
<div #normalComments *ngIf="commentsDisplayed && comments">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let comment of comments; let i = index">
        <post-comment
          class="comment-{{i}}"
          [user]="user"
          [comment]="comment"
          [allMembersId]="allMembersId"
          (sendDeletedComment)="deleteComment($event)">
        </post-comment>
    </ng-container>

</div>
```

**SCSS code: I add the animation to every class that starts with `comment-` and the animation-delay depends on the index number of the element**

```
[class^="comment-"] {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.comment {
  &-0 {
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }

  &-1 {
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }

  &-2 {
    animation-delay: 3s;
  }

  &-3 {
    animation-delay: 4s;
  }

  &-4 {
    animation-delay: 5s;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code for your comment class animation

```
  @for $i from 0 through 4 {
     .comment-#{$i} {
         animation-name: fadeIn;
         animation-duration: 1s;
         animation-delay: $i+1s;
        }
    }
```

indetead of

```
[class^="comment-"] {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
.comment {
  &-0 {
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }

  &-1 {
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }

  &-2 {
    animation-delay: 3s;
  }

  &-3 {
    animation-delay: 4s;
  }

  &-4 {
    animation-delay: 5s;
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool solution, but unfortunately the animation still doesn't appear :/

Comment: try with before  <post-comment . place one div and add you class...may be helpfull